# This file has been added after the last project sync with Gradle.Please sync the project again for the NDK support to work properly

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0g2l.png)

[image]

my project contain java and c++ files ,now my questions is i cannot debug the native c++ file (java file debug is ok),when i open the c++ file it show “This file has been added after the last project sync with Gradle.Please sync the project again for the NDK support to work properly” in the top

i try to click the "Sync Now" button,it show build successful in the gradle console ,but zhe top bar show still,and i still cannot debug the c++ file step by step

please give me some ideas for debug c++ file ,thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of Android Studio?  I think NDK debugging is only available in 2.2 preview 4 +

Comment: really?only 2.2?    my AS version is 2.1.2 ,this version is the latest verion from android offical website,where can i get the 2.2 preview 4?

Comment: 2.2 is Available from the Canary channel and also here http://tools.android.com  Note these are unstable pre-release builds.

Comment: java file debug is ok using AS 2.1.2 and c++ file is not work .

Comment: i used 2.2p4version ,it really work when the project contain c++ file is simple,but it still cannot debug for my project (a complex project contain man .so and .a files)